# Any ideas on How to search a 2D array quickly?

Tags: arrays, optimization, programming-languages, matrix, logic

I jave a 2D array like this, just like a matrix:

```
{{1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6},
{8, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2},
{8, 3, 4, 2, 6, 2},
//code skips... ...

}
```

(The Array is not sorted)
I want to get all the "4" position, instead of searching the array one by one, and return the position, how can I search it faster / more efficient? thz in advance.

Comment: You have to perform M*N comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose speed or memory consumption. If Memory is not important you could create a List of positions where values are stored. So you have still your m*n array, but additionaly an array of "position-lists". You would have to create "setter"-methods which write down a position in the lists each time a value is added or changed. So the idea is not to improve the search but avoid it.

Example:

You have a 2*2 Array.

```
{{0,0}
 {0,0}}
```

And you want to add a 4 in the . So you have to call your method write which is called with the parameters X, Y, and Value. This method would change your array to

```
{{4,0},
 {0,0}}
```

but also create a list

```
List4=>{(0,0)}
```

with the position of fours. If you add a second 4 it would look like

```
{{4,0}
 {4,0}}
List4=>{(0,0),(1,0)}
```

So if you want to find all 4 in your matrix you just have to go to all positions in your List4. Of course you would have to create a list for each value in your array. So you could have a maximum of m*n lists with positions if the matrix contains each value only once.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. There is no magic way. Your algorithm will always need to check each cell in your matrix, so it will always be `O(n*m)` for a matrix of size `n * m`.

If you can *sort* your matrix first, then you can get away with `O(log(n) * m)`, as you can use a binary search inside each row.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is less than `m * n` is to have it presorted in some way. It is not clear from your question if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no obvious algorithmic optimisation (unless you have some *a priori* knowledge of the data, e.g. that it's sorted, or you know how many 4s there are). However there are micro-optimisations that you can use, e.g. if your array is 32 bit int and you can use SSE then you can load and compare 4 elements at a time.